# Form for many to many relationship in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On an MVC view I need to display a form to insert user data and its courses.

For each course the user must choose: name, number of days and location.

And the user can choose many courses ... I don't know how many.

So basically this a form with a many to many relationship.

What options do I have for such a form that is easy to use?

Answer (score 0):

You should have some entry points like a user or a course to view its details. For example, if you go to details of a user, you can see all the registered courses in a table/grid, you can have an autocomplete dropdown box for adding a new course. You can apply the same thing for a course details page as well.